# Number of Connected component in undirected graph

Tags: python, graph

I'm very confused on how to solve this problem using Python. Please do NOT solve it for me as I'm learning Python and getting full soultions won't help. Say that I have the follwing input:

```
1
0,4
3
2
1
```

Where the first line is node 0 and the second line is node 1 etc... (5 nodes in this example).
The answer to this program should be "2" as there are 2 "islands" of connected component. one is 2-3 and the second one is 0-1-4. Any tips on how to compute this answer from the given input above would be much appreciated. Thanks! BTW, I'm an 11th grade student so my knowledge of coding is limited, go ez on me :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's hard to help if we don't know where you've started.

Comment: @JoanSmith I've tried appending nodes to a list if they are not there already and if they aren't, create a new list and start appending there. I do understand how to solve this problem on paper and I don understand why my code doesn't work but I have no idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: Edit your question to include your understanding of how to solve to problem on paper, and give the code you've already implemented that doesn't work.

Comment: @JoanSmith, that's exactly not what OP is looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the ASCII-based representation of the graph into a decent Python structure (a `dict` of node → list_of_edges would do fine for small graphs).
2. Perform a flooding algorithm on the first unvisited node (visit every node reachable from there).
3. Continue with step 2 and count how often you find a still-unvisited node.

This terminates when you find no unvisited node anymore.